# Running UVM example on MODELSIM - ALTERA 10.1d

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim, verification

I want to compile and simulate this simple UVM example using Modelsim-Altera 10.1d tool.

```
 module uvm_first_ex;
 import uvm_pkg::*;
 `include "uvm_macros.svh"
 initial begin
   `uvm_info("ID","WELCOME TO UVM",UVM_MEDIUM);
 end  
 endmodule:uvm_first_ex
```

I get error when I try to compile the above code. But I have heard that UVM is supported by Modelsim except randomization. It would be helpful to me if anybody can suggest me something on this. Ofcouse I can use EDA playground but I was wondering how to do it in Modelsim-Altera while the same can be done on EDA playground using modelsim tool itself.

This is the error message I get :

```
** Error: G:/Verilog/uvm_ex1.sv(2): Could not find the package (uvm_pkg). 
Design read will continue, but expect a cascade of errors after this failure.
Furthermore if you experience a vopt-7 error immediately before this error then
please check the package names or the library search paths on the command line.  
** Error: G:/Verilog/uvm_ex1.sv(3): Cannot open `include file "uvm_macros.svh".  
** Error: G:/Verilog/uvm_ex1.sv(5): (vlog-2163) Macro ``uvm_info is undefined.  
** Error: G:/Verilog/uvm_ex1.sv(5): near "(": syntax error, unexpected '('
```

Comment: What is your error message? Did you define `$UVM_HOME` and include `+incdir+$UVM_HOME/src $UVM_HOME/src/uvm.sv` in your `vlog` arguments?

Comment: This is the error message I get :

** Error: G:/Verilog/uvm_ex1.sv(2): Could not find the package (uvm_pkg).  Design read will continue, but expect a cascade of errors after this failure.  Furthermore if you experience a vopt-7 error immediately before this error then please check the package names or the library search paths on the command line.
** Error: G:/Verilog/uvm_ex1.sv(3): Cannot open `include file "uvm_macros.svh".
** Error: G:/Verilog/uvm_ex1.sv(5): (vlog-2163) Macro `uvm_info is undefined.

** Error: G:/Verilog/uvm_ex1.sv(5): near "(": syntax error, unexpected '('

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error message, you are not including the UVM source in your compile. Some tools have UVM built-in that can be enabled with the `-uvm` argument at compile time (refer to the user manual).

Alternatively you can add `+incdir+$UVM_HOME/src $UVM_HOME/src/uvm.sv` as a compile time argument, where `$UVM_HOME` is the path to the UVM source. This method works even if your simulator does not include UVM, but does support SystemVerilog. You can download UVM (source and manual) at http://www.accellera.org/downloads/standards/uvm

Comment: How do i do that? I wanted step by step procedure for it.